# R Shiny - how to share variables between Rendering functions?

Tags: r, shiny

I have variables that I get from ui.R and I want to use them in renderUI and renderPlot functions such as below,

```
shinyServer(

  function(input, output, session) {

  output$text <- renderUI({

      # Sites.
      site1 = input$site1
      site2 = input$site2
      site3 = input$site3
      site4 = input$site4

    })

    output$plot = renderPlot({

      # Sites.
      site1 = input$site1
      site2 = input$site2
      site3 = input$site3
      site4 = input$site4

    })

})
```

I have to **repeat the variables twice**, is there any way I can put them in **one place** and **share** them between the functions? I will get error if I put the variables outside these functions.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe `site1 <- reactive({input$site1})` then calling `site1()` in your `renderPlot` would work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create another reactive function that returns a list, like this:

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {

    site <- reactive({
      unlist(list("site1" = input$site1, 
                  "site2" = input$site2, 
                  "site3" = input$site3, 
                  "site4" = input$site4))
    }

    output$text <- renderUI({
         site = site()
    })

    output$plot = renderPlot({
         site = site()
    })
})
```

Then you can call *site1* by simply doing `site[1]`.

Hope this helps!